# Detect if Exchange MAPI is installed

Tags: exchange-server, mapi

Since Exchange 2007, MAPI is no longer installed when Exchange is installed. On these systems [this install](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=e17e7f31-079a-43a9-bff2-0a110307611e&DisplayLang=en) is needed in addition to Exchange if you want to use MAPI.

My software depends on Exchange MAPI, so I need to detect if its installed. How can I reliably test if MAPI is installed on the local machine? First prise will be if I can also know if its Exchange MAPI or outlook MAPI and if its 32 bit or the new 64 bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\Mail\ExchangeMAPI key exists and read the DllPathEx string value.
Exchange (standalone) version fo MAPI is always 32 bit.
64 bit version of MAPI is only installed if Outlook 2010 64 bit is installed.

Comment: Really? I ask Outlook 2010 will not install if MAPI & CDO is installed on the system and vice versa. "Messaging API and Collaboration Data Objects 1.2.1 cannot be installed with Microsoft Outlook"

Comment: The standalone version of MAPI will not install if Outlook is installed, but I don't think Outlook will refuse to install on top of standalone version of MAPI.

Comment: If you have the standalone version of MAPI installed before Outlook, you get the error that a "Outlook 2010 may not be installed with a newer version" the only way to proceed with the installation is to remove MAPI. I personally had this [issue](http://superuser.com/questions/565757/outlook-may-not-be-installed-with-a-newer-version-of-outlook).

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me the answer of Dmitry isn't correct.

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients` contains a (Default) value. If this value is set, it is set to the name of a subkey. That might be `ExchangeMAPI`, but it might also be something else. In my case it is set to "`Microsoft Outlook`". Under this subkey, you can look for the `DLLPath` or `DLLPathEx` values.